# JSP and SQL Data insertion

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Currently I'm having a bugin my JSP while trying to insert data into a a Database. Im using Java class to do this to avoid the scriplets at all cost. Thing is that when I want to insert data into 3 different tables, only the first table gets fill while doing this in JSP. You know filling forms, sending data to class and there the database gets fill. YET if I do it stand alone Java App, all tables get filled up in only one function. JSP doesnt work, Java app does? What?

This is the java class:

```
public void fileDataToDB(String file1, String file2, String file3, String aPath, String operationUsed) {


        try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connectMe = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName, userNameDB, passwordDB);

        String query = "INSERT INTO MatrixUsers.FilePath (idFilePath, LocationFiles) VALUES (?, ?)";
        String query2 = "INSERT INTO MatrixUsers.Sessions (idSessions, Matrix1, Matrix2, Result) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        String query3 = "INSERT INTO MatrixUsers.Operations (idOperations, Operation) VALUES (?,?)";


        selectUsers = connectMe.prepareStatement(query2);

        selectUsers.setInt(1, id);
        selectUsers.setString(2, file1);
        selectUsers.setString(3, file2);
        selectUsers.setString(4, file3);
        selectUsers.executeUpdate();

        tip1 = "First table done!";

        if(aPath != null)
            contains = "Path is filled!";

        selectUsers.close();


        selectUsers = connectMe.prepareStatement(query);

        selectUsers.setInt(1, id);
        selectUsers.setString(2, aPath);

        selectUsers.executeUpdate();

        tip2 = "Second table done!";

        selectUsers.close();

        selectUsers = connectMe.prepareStatement(query3);

        selectUsers.setInt(1, id);
        selectUsers.setString(2, operationUsed);
        selectUsers.executeUpdate();

        tip3 = "Third table done!";

        selectUsers.close();

        connectMe.close(); 


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

NOTE: I use this in the JSP and Java app and is the same. The TIPS variables are only used to know where does the code cut. In the JSP it cuts at first table, the others return null meaning the other queries never get executed. Also the container variable is to know if the aPath variable is fill and it returns that contains something. So I think those to doubts are out of question. Why does it cut like that? When this is exacly the same in the Java app.

Comment: If tip2 and tip3 are null after executing the function, then an exception must have been thrown.  In your catch block, you are printing the stack trace.  We need to see that stack trace to see what error was thrown.  You will find the stack trace printed in your app server log.

Comment: Where can I find the app server log? Sorry Im new to JSP. :S Im using Linux Ubuntu for this.

Comment: Which app server/container are you using to host your JSP pages? Tomcat? JBoss?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, Im using Tomcat7.

Comment: You should find logs in logs directory, usually catalina.out file

Comment: Check in the tomcat installation/log directory.  There should be a file with a name something like catalina.2014-02-13.log or tomcat7-stderr.2015-02-13.log

Comment: Found the log file. Thanks! I'm looking at it right now and I believe that the strings that are going to fill the rows are bigger than the row size, I'll change it and get back to you guys!

Comment: NOTE: Found that the size of the row was smaller than the string I was trying to get in. Its working now! Thanks for the log file tip. Makes troubleshooting more easier!

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION: Row was smaller than the String aPath, changed row size from varchar(45) to varchar(255) and problem solved!

Thanks to **dave823 and cigno5.5** for the info on the log file.